# Add to collection one document that is one field's accumulation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I add to a collection one document that accumulate the value collection's field in MongoDB?

I have a MongoDB collection with documents in the following format:

```
{
  "_id" : 3876435465554,
  "title" : "xxx",
  "category" : "xxx",
  ...
}
```

So the desire result would be:

```
{ "_id" : "All", "num" : 28 }  // <- This is the document that I want include in the output
{ "_id" : "xxx", "num" : 11 }
{ "_id" : "yyy", "num" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "zzz", "num" : 9 }
```

So far I've tried this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { title:1, category:1} },
  { $group: {
      _id: { _id:"$category"},
      num: { $sum: 1 }
    } },
  { $project: { _id:"$_id._id", num:1} },
  { $sort: { _id:1} }
])
```

But that produce just the documents **without the "All" document**:

```
{ "_id" : "xxx", "num" : 11 }
{ "_id" : "yyy", "num" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "zzz", "num" : 9 }
```

I dont know how to add the "All" document with the sum of all "num" values.

**Note**: Chaining 2 calls to `aggregate`s I was able to get the desire output in the program, but the idea is to get the output with just one `aggregate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query in 3.4.

Changes include adding extra `$group` to calculate total count while pushing the individual count rows into array followed by `$concatArrays` to add the total row document to individual count array.

`$unwind` to go back to flat structure and $sort by _id and `$replaceRoot` to promote all the docs to top level.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$project":{"title":1,"category":1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"_id":"$category"},"num":{"$sum":1}}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "total":{"$sum":"$num"},
    "rest":{"$push":{"num":"$num","_id":"$_id._id"}}
  }},
  {"$project":{"data":{"$concatArrays":[[{"_id":"all","num":"$total"}],"$rest"]}}},
  {"$unwind":"$data"},
  {"$sort":{"data._id":1}},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
])
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"total":{"$sum":"$num"}` in the second `$group` ?

Comment: @Alex Blex yep. thanks. corrected. Looks like you missed it too :)

Comment: @Veeram, No, I am using facets to group in parallel, so it should be `$sum:1` in both pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can "chain" the pipelines on the db side using [$facets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html), so it will be single request from the client:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { category: { $ne: 'all' } } },
  { $project: { title:1, category:1 } },
  { $facet: {
      total: [ 
        { $group: {
          _id: 'all', 
          num: { $sum: 1 }
         } },
      ],
      categories: [   
        { $group: {
          _id: "$category",
          num: { $sum: 1 }
         } },
      ]
  } },
  { $project: { all: { $concatArrays: [ "$total", "$categories" ] } } },
  { $unwind: "$all" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$all" } },  
  { $sort: { _id:1 } }
])
```

Comment: Thank you @AlexBlex, Let me try your solution as well.